# Convert GMT date format to only time format

Tags: json, angularjs, datetime

I am building an html application using AngularJS wherein I want to display the json file data on html page. Can anyone help me to Convert GMT date format from json file to hour:minutes AM/PM

Json file looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "startTime": "Sun May 24 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "endTime": "Sun May 24 2015 01:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 1"
    },
    {
        "startTime": "Sun May 24 2015 04:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "endTime": "Sun May 24 2015 06:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 2"
    },
    {
        "startTime": "Sat May 23 2015 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "endTime": "Sat May 23 2015 21:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 3"
    },
    {
        "startTime": "Sat May 23 2015 21:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "endTime": "Sat May 23 2015 22:15:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 4"
    },
    {
        "startTime": "Sun May 24 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "endTime": "Sun May 24 2015 03:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 5"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided by @worldask says

> Date to format either as **Date object**, **milliseconds** (string or number) or **various ISO 8601**
>   datetime string formats (e.g. yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter
>   versions like yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If
>   no timezone is specified in the string input, the time is considered
>   to be in the local timezone.

So I am using a custom filter for converting `Sun May 24 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` to [milliseconds](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) and then using angular filter to show as `hh:mm AM/PM`

HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="date in dateJson">
      {{date.startTime | myDateFilter | date:'hh: mm a' }}
</div>
```

dateJson is your sample json...

custom filter

```
app.filter('myDateFilter', function() {

  return function(dateString) {
    var date = new Date(dateString)

    // converting to milliseconds
    dateString = date.getTime();
    return dateString;
  }
});
```

[SAMPLE PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/OPJwv1Syd6BOquxORpfD?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

assign your json data to a scope variable:

```
scope.data = [
    {
        "startTime": "Sun May 24 2015 01:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "endTime": "Sun May 24 2015 01:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)",
        "title": "Event 1"
    },
    ...
];
```

in your html, you can use [angularjs date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) like this:

```
<div>{{ data[0] | date: 'h:m a' }}</div>
```

Comment: for showing AM/PM you can use the filter like `{{ data | date: 'h:m a' }}`